# New Azure Standard LB doesn't allow inbound connection

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-networking

I have setup a LB with a backend pool (only one host for test).
I setup network security group on test host with following rule:

Source: AzureLoadBalancer Destination: Any Action: Allow
Source: VirtualNetwork Destination: VirtualNetwork Action: Allow
Source: Any Destination: Any Action: Deny

I can't connect to host through LB (from host in the same VNET)

If I setup a rule
Source: Any Destination: Any Action: Allow

All work fine.

Of course, I don't want this rule.

What's wrong with my setup ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Even going through a LB the source will still be your host and not the LB. All the LB does is forward the connection based on a set of rules and does not change the originating address of the clnnectkon.

You will need to edit the NSG to allow connections from the host itself (either public IP or internal) and not the LB as the connection comes from the host instead.

Comment: @Kiva - Does this help with your question?